# What is this structure on PCB

Tags: pcb

My LED TV is broken, so I disassembled it, and saw this weird thing on the power stage:
[image: weird filling]

Above it, there are two 3 ohm resistors. (owners of the large drill holes in image) What could be the purpose of these? The only thing I came up with is that it is a clever use of solder to help the resistor from overheating. Is that the case here? How much of a difference - approximately - would they make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a PCB heat sink. They left holes in the solder mask so solder would adhere to the copper pour to add surface area to improve heat rejection.

Comment: Nice pic btw.. I was looking for something like that a week ago for another question.

Comment: That is nice. Are these common in high power (like this TV) application? This is the first time I see something like this.

Comment: It's one of those.. "it's free so use it" situations if you have clear space under a power part.